# Is the Ethernet port on mother board of my desktop dead?

Tags: ethernet, network-adapter, pci, gigabit-ethernet

The desktop was switched on and it was raining while I fell asleep. I got up instantly after hearing a loud thunder and lightening. I did hear few spiking sound within the cabinet and In a fear I switched off the computer directly. After few hours I turned it on and found there was no internet. (Cross mark on computer icon)
But I'm able to access Internet from my mobile phone through the router. 
What I did:
1. There was no light glowing in the port.
2. I changed the Ethernet cable and ports on router.
3. I saw "network cable unplugged" in computer connections.
4. LAN is already enabled. 
5. In device manager, I can see "this device is working properly"

What could be the cause? Is Ethernet port dead? If yes, What are the alternatives to fix it? Should I buy a PCI network adapter for my gigabyte mother board? If yes, how can I find a compatible one?

Comment: "Is Ethernet port dead?" - Yes;  "What are the alternatives to fix it?" - Replace it with a PCI-E Ethernet LAN card.  "Should I buy a PCI network adapter for my gigabyte mother board?" - Yes; "If yes, how can I find a compatible one?" - Simply by shopping for PCI-E network cards  Hardware recommendations are not within scope here at Superuser.

Comment: I'll look into that.. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good chance that the ethernet port is dead, but you can't be 100% sure without testing some other wired ethernet device on the same port from the router. It's possible the router was also damaged. If you have a laptop with ethernet you could try connecting that to the router to make sure that the ports on the router still work.

If you are comfortable opening up your computer and working on it then a new PCI card would be a good choice.

Please note that some newer computers don't have regular PCI slots anymore. Some of them only have PCI express. If that is the case then you can get a PCI express 1x card like this:

[PCI Express 1x Network Card](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106033&cm_re=pci_express_network_card-_-33-106-033-_-Product)

Honestly, if it was me I would do the newer PCI Express card anyway. Standard PCI is an old format and it's much slower and larger.

Comment: Router is working fine and yes the port is dead. I'll be replacing with a new PCIe 1x network card.